# Synchronise/Merge MP3 collections without duplication or huge copies

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, hard-drive, mp3

I have one drive containing about 90GB of MP3s which is used at home, it serves three Squeezebox players though the Slimserver software running on one of the desktop Macs.

I have a separate firewire drive containing about the same amount of music which I am very slowly cleaning up with [Song Genie](http://www.equinux.com/us/products/songgenie/index.html) and I've finished the process of getting all the covers in better than 300x300 using [CoverScout](http://www.equinux.com/us/products/coverscout/index.html). Good tools if you are prepared to work more or less manually, they can come up with some pretty strange suggestions for covers & tag info at times. All this is from CDs I have in storage and I've even scanned some of the covers I couldn't find online. It's a long-term project and one day I want to know all of it is perfect.

Some of the music on the home collection isn't on my firewire drive, and vice versa. If I copy all of the firewire contents over the home collection that would probably work. However I'd really like to know what music is in the home collection that I haven't got because there's no way I'm copying un-tagged un-covered music over my fixed versions.

I could copy all the firewire drive MP3s over the home drive, then call the home drive contents the new cleanest and completest version but copy 90GB twice seems like a waste of time and there must be a clever way to do it?

Comment: iCloud is taking care of this, mostly. It's worth a bounty in case anyone has a really clever solution. Is there some Mac-based deduplication technology that could help? (and this could also apply to images)

Comment: You could have a look at [dupeGuru Music Edition](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_me/) - I haven't used it myself, but it sounds helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a merge/sync solution.  I personally often use [arRsync](http://arrsync.sourceforge.net/) - but there are lots.  Find one that allows you to prioritize one folder over the other when a match is found.  You may need to tag and apply album art to both copies, before they will be recognized as the same, though.

Comment: +1 for using a rsync based solution. I wrote a blog post about this specific issue (synchronizing music libraries using rsync) : http://tunecrux.com/restoring-files-scattered-backup-drive-rsync

Comment: @kraymer - juicy looking blog post!  Looks pretty technical, it's tickling my need to know stuff.  :-)  I will read it later, thanks for sharing.